# Want to change special charcter in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like  request[0][level2][0][level3][1][designation] and i want to replace only 1 ([1][designation]). I tried split function but not getting proper way.

Is there any way to do this. I want to change before designation bracket value like [1].

This is simple name attribute of an select box and i want to change it in foreach loop. hope you understand

Thanks in advance

My code is

```
var cnt = 0;
    $(this).children('tr').each(function(){

        var Getname=$(this).children('td').children('select').attr('name');
        //Getname is request[0][level2][0][level3][1][designation]
        //var newname=
        $(this).children('td').children('select').attr('name', newname);
        cnt++;

    });

 request[0][level2][0][level3][1][designation]
```

in which request[0] can be request[1] so i want change only [1][designation]

Comment: please add the object (simplified), the assingment and the wanted result (in text form)

Comment: Thanks and Can you please explain more. I am new in jqery

Comment: without knowing, what you like to get with unknown date, it's hard to help.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: this is simple name and want to change 1 before designation.

Comment: `request[0][level2][0][level3][1][designation]` this is your string or is this returning string you want to change?

Comment: yes this is my string and want to make [1] this dynamic in each loop of jquery

Comment: actually i want to change this order, can be 1, 2. Hope you understand

Comment: *"want to make [1] this dynamic"*: I have absolutely no idea what that means. Can you please provide an ***example*** of input and desired output.

Comment: Is there any way to do this ??

Comment: Provide concrete examples of input and desired output.

Comment: I updated my question with my code

Comment: Now tell us what do you want that `1` to be?

Comment: Yes, but you did not add the *desired output*. This was already asked in the first comment above. Can you explain what you expect as a result, ... concretely.

Comment: You write *"change only [1][designation]"*. The question is: change into what? What should the value of `newname` be?

Comment: okay, this  request[0][level2][0][level3][1][designation]    is a name of select box and it is under a <tr> tag and i applied drag function of jquery. so when i am draging a row from bottom to top then i want to change this order in  request[0][level2][0][level3][1][designation]

Comment: So you want to change the order. Into what? Please provide what `newname` should be. Should it be `request[0][level2][0][level3][1][designation]`, or `request[0][level2][0][level3][designation][1]` or `[designation][1][level3][0][level2][0]request` or just `[1][designation]` or `[designation][1]`, or still something else. It is not clear what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the string, clean it, replace the wanted value, map the wanted structure and join it to a single string.

```js
var string = 'request[0][level2][0][level3][1][designation]',
    parts = string.split(/[[\]]/).filter(Boolean),
    result;
    
parts[5] = 42;
result = parts.map((v, i) => i ? `[${v}]` : v).join('');

console.log(string);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what i need.

Answer (score 0):

**String.prototype.split()** is going to return an array.

If I understand correct what you need to accomplish, you should use replace.

```
var text = "request[0][level2][0][level3][1][designation]";
var target = "[1][designation]";
var newText = text.replace("[1][designation]", " text of your choice ");
```